# Handle function in const class?

Tags: javascript, html

I have source code like this

```
  const item = function(p) {
     let model;
     p.setup = function() {
     }
  }
```

I am not sure how should I call this `class`? `function component`?

What I want to do is add my function to this and call this function from outside.

```
  const item = function(p) {
     let model;
     p.setup = function() {
     }
     function nextGame(){
         console.log("test");
     }
  }
  item.nextGame(); // error
```

However it doesn't work.

I am not familiar this style of javascript.

How should I add the function to this(is it class??) and call??

Comment: The OP assigns an anonymous function to the `item` constant. This function has no other properties than the ones it inherits from `Function.prototype`. Thus there is definitely no own `nextGame` property on the `item` reference available.

Comment: The above provided example code could be rewritten and interpolated/interpreted into 3 different builder patterns. The OP can choose from [`class` syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#class_body_and_method_definitions), an old school but not entirely obsolete pure [constructor function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new) based solution or a function based factory pattern.

Comment: You probably want to use [Classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) instead.

Comment: In order to know how to rewrite the code in a meaningful way into some of the possible variants one actually needs to know an item's basic model structure and also how the OP wants to manage state and the access-handling / visibility of item properties.

Comment: @whitebear ... From all the provided solutions/approaches are there any questions left?

Comment: @whitebear ... At SO it is considered to be a nice gesture from the one who got help, to provide some feedback and/or vote on answers and/or accept the answer which was the most helpful in solving the OP's problem.

Answer (score 1):

For object-oriented programming in javascript there are a few methods, as mentioned in the comments.

### 1. Factory Function

A factory function is a simple approach, as it just creates and returns an object.

```js
function Item(model) {
  const item = {
    model,
    nextGame: () => { console.log('test') }
  }
  return item
}

const itemInstance = Item('Tesla');

itemInstance.nextGame()
console.log(itemInstance.model)
```

### 2. Constructor Function

Uses the [new](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new) keyword to create an instance of the defined object type. It utilizes the function's [prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Object_prototypes), which is accessible on all instances of the type.

```js
function Item(model) {
    this.model = model;
}

Item.prototype.nextGame = () => { console.log('test') }

const itemInstance = new Item('Tesla');

itemInstance.nextGame()
console.log(itemInstance.model)
```

### 3. Class

You could also use a [Class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes). Classes in javascript are provided as an abstraction of functions.

```js
class Item {
  constructor(model) {
    this.model = model
  }
  
  nextGame() {
    console.log('test')
  }
}

const itemInstance = new Item('Tesla');

itemInstance.nextGame()
console.log(itemInstance.model)
```

Answer (score 0):

What you describe and demonstrate in your snippet javascript is an anonymous function, you could even say that it is a functional variable.

To access methods using dot notation, you need to create a class (or javascript object).

example using the keyword 'class':

```
class MyClass 
{
   var name;
   var lastName;
   
   constructor(_name, _lastname)
   {
      this.name = _name;
      this.lastName = _lastname;
   }
   
   sayMyName()
   {
     window.alert(`${this.name} ${this.lastname}`);
   }
}
```

Now create an instance of this class. Like this:

```
const myName = new MyClass("John", "Doe");
```

and now call with the method of your class using notation. Like this:

```
myName.sayMyName();
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
class Item {

  // private field for whatever
  // got passed to the constructor.
  #value;

  constructor(value) {
    this.#value = value;
  }
  
  // prototypal methods with access to
  // private fields and private methods.

  setup() {
    // do something with `this.#value`
    console.log(this.#value);
  }
  nextGame() {
    console.log("next game");
  }  
}

const item = new Item("OP's mysterious `p` value");

console.log({ item });

console.log('item.setup() ...');
item.setup();

console.log('item.nextGame() ...');
item.nextGame();
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```